# How to keep a value same inside of the update method in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that gets a transform value from a script that completes the getting operation by using its update method and also I use this value after getting it in another script that also uses this value inside of its update method too. So, what I want to do is that, once I get the value, I want the value to be the same even if the starting value of it changes. I cannot assign them at the start function because everything happens at the runtime. I tried to create a method to assign this value and even if I used an if statement which causes the method called for once, it still changes its value.

So here is the lines of codes that I use and they are all inside of the Update method.

```c#
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(i);
    if (DragAndDrop.finding == true)
    {
         B = DragAndDrop.lastposofmodel;
```

here where I use the assigned value

```c#
if (modelobject.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled == true) 
{
    repmodel = modelobject.collider.gameObject;
    finding = true;
    modelobject.collider.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(modelobject.collider.gameObject.transform.position.x, 
                 modelobject.collider.gameObject.transform.position.y, 
                 modelobject.collider.gameObject.transform.position.z - 0.1f);

    lastposofmodel = modelobject.collider.gameObject.transform;
```

and this is where the value is assigned.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what exactly your goal / question is ... could you add a bit more context of your code?

Comment: What I want to do is that, after getting the value with the second script that you see, and assigning that value to the another value that you can see from the first script, and keeping the value the same even if it is in the update method.

Comment: so why should it not stay the same? Does your second script change it meanwhile? Maybe it would be enough to say e.g. `if(!B) B = DragAndDrop.lastposofmodel;` ? So `B` stays the same forever unless it gets destroyed

Comment: Why it is not the same , I think, is because they are in the update method but I'll try what you've suggested.

Comment: well it is a bit hard to tell when and how exactly the bottom code block is called and why you need to pass on the reference via multiple scripts

Comment: I get the position from a raycast method, thus I use multiple scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that B is a static value and therefore is called by reference and not by value. So if you want to keep the value B unique for every script you maybe should create an instance for every representation of that value for every script.

Comment: If something is called by reference or by value is a question of the field **type** ... if its a class type it is always by reference. If it's a struct or base type like `int` it is called by value ... has nothing to do with `static`